# How to date/timestamp for modifications in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a sheet that has information in 8 columns starting in row 14. I would like I14:I310 to date stamp anytime there is an update in the corresponding row. I have tried a couple of different ways and haven't found anything to be successful as of yet. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add this script to your sheet and change format and time zone if you need so 
  (`"GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy"`):

---

```
function onEdit(event)
    { var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      // note: actRng = the cell being updated
      var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
      var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
      var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();
      var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
      var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy");
      lastCell.setValue(date);
    }
```

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_W8UvcKMIus7uYn_SPwH0Ftl9zSKLQZY2DCEiv33oe8/edit#gid=0)**